# React refs of nested 2nd level object

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

Suppose this structure

```
const Foo = () => {
    const bazRefs = React.useRef<Array<HTMLDivElement | null>>([]); // List of Baz wanted

    return <div>{[0, 1, 2, 3].map((i) => <Bar ref={(el) => (bazRefs.current[i] = el)} />)}</div>
}

const Bar = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>(({ }, ref) => {
    return <div>{[0, 1, 2].map(() => <Baz />)}</div>
})

const Baz = () => {
    return <div ref={ref}>Test</div>
}
```

I know that with the callback I can get a list of `Bar` but how about an agreagated list of `Baz` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of Refs in `Foo` component and use for loop to assign the initial value:

```
  for (...){
    myRef = useRef()
  }
```

Then you can pass it to child components accordily.